# 2-transitivity of the group of automorphism on unit complex disc

Tags: complex-analysis

In M. Abate “Iteration theory of Holomorphic maps on Taut Manifolds”, Corollary 1.1.3 proves the 2-transitivity of $Aut(\Delta)$ over $\partial\Delta$, which means that for every choice of $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\tau_1,\tau_2\in\partial\Delta$, there exists a unique $\gamma\in Aut(\Delta)$ such that $\gamma(\sigma_i)=\tau_i$ for $i=1,2$.
In the proof the author says that it is enough to prove that $\forall \tau\in\partial\Delta$ there exists a unique $\gamma\in Aut(\Delta)$ such that $\gamma(1)=1$ and $\gamma(-1)=\tau$. 
My question is how to prove that this is sufficient. Here I show my attempt. 
Let $R_{\sigma_1}$ and $R_{\tau_1}$ be the rotations of complex plane which map $\sigma_1$ and $\tau_1$ to $1$ respectively. Of course $R_{\sigma_1}, R_{\tau_1}\in Aut(\Delta)$. Define $\eta:=R_{\tau_1}^{-1}\circ\gamma\circ R_{\sigma_1}\in Aut(\Delta)$ for some $\gamma$ as above. Thus we have:
$$\eta(\sigma_1)= R_{\tau_1}^{-1}\circ\gamma(1)= R_{\tau_1}^{-1}(1)=\tau_1.$$
But how can we define $\gamma(-1)$ in order to have $\eta(\sigma_2)=\tau_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be an automorphism of the disk, $s=\sigma_2/\sigma_1, t=\tau_2/\tau_1$. Write $u=R_{\tau_1} \circ w \circ R_{\sigma_1}^{-1}$. Then $u(\sigma_i)=\tau_i$ for each $i$ iff $w(1)=1$ and $w(s)=t$.

Now, there are automorphisms $w^s,w^t$ of the disk mapping respectively $(1,-1) \longmapsto (1,s)$ and $(1,-1) \longmapsto (1,t)$, so take $w=w^t \circ (w^s)^{-1}$.

Comment: Assuming that those two automorphisms exist is equivalent to the initial problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Giulio Binosi: you’re asking why the case $\sigma_1=\tau_1=1,\sigma_2=-1$ implies the general case, aren’t you? The existence of $w^s,w^t$ stems from that very case...

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking for, sorry. Thank you very much!